# Tidying a barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm trying to practice data analysis with r with a police killings data set, when I'm filtering it by cities I get a huge barplot, that I can't analyze cause the most important variables doesn't show, how can I get a more decent barplot, I already try las=2 but it stills look awful.

```
barplot(prop.table(table(losdatosCA$X8)), las=2,cex.names = 0.3)
```

[image: Barplot that i got but sucks]

Comment: You want one barplot with lots of labels, what do you expect?

Comment: I want to get a decent graphic or there is a way that i can show in the graph the city with the max frecuency or the three higher?

Comment: Try `sort`, `barplot(sort(prop.table(table(losdatosCA$X8)))[1:3], las=2, cex.names=0.3)`.

Comment: It just show me the first three values

Comment: It doesn't show the max three it only shows the first three like A, the first is Los Angeles

Comment: `barplot(sort(prop.table(table(losdatosCA$X8)),decreasing=TRUE)[1:15], las=2, cex.names=1,)` This one works just fine, thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine for the max values 1 to 15

```
barplot(sort(prop.table(table(losdatosCA$X8)),decreasing=TRUE)[1:15], las=2, cex.names=1,)
```